# invertibility of specific matrix through calculation of its rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an $n\times n$ matrix of the form
$A=\begin{bmatrix}
    1        & 1 & \dots & 1 \\
    x_{1} & x_{2} & \dots & x_{n} \\
     x_{1}^2 & x_{2}^2 & \dots & x_{n}^2 \\
 \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
    x_{1}^{n-1} & x_{2}^{n-1} & \dots & x_{n}^{n-1}
\end{bmatrix}$
where I know that every pair of $x_i$ is distinct. I would like to show that $A$ is invertible by showing that it has full rank but I can't find a way to prove that. I don't really need a proof rather than a confirmation whether A is invertible or not and if my idea (about the rank) will work. Thank you!

Comment: Estimating the rank of this will be hard to do. On the other hand, this is a Vandermonde matrix (or a Vandermonde matrix's transpose, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)), so the condition on the $x_{i}'s$ is sufficient for invertibility.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot! :)